# Wikipedia : Escape Brackets inside of Link

Tags: wikipedia

I'm trying to create 2 different links on a Wikipedia Artist page. One link should go to a website called "Insert [IMG]" located at www.insertimg.com and the other would be to a Wikipedia.org page for his comic wikipedia.org/InsertIMG.

However, when creating the link [[Insert [IMG]]] the brackets in the name of Insert [IMG] screw everything up. How do I work around this?

Comment: what is the exact `http://` link you want it to open?

Comment: meaning, when you visit "Insert [IMG]" site in your browser, what is the site address at the top of the page?

Comment: I 'technically' need to do two different links...

Comment: One link should point to his website: www.insertimg.com
[[Insert [IMG]|http://insertimg.com]] (maybe?)
And the other should go to a Wiki page: wikipedia.org/InsertIMG
[[Insert [IMG]]]]

Comment: what is the link to the wiki article? I'll take a look at it on there.

Comment: I'm a newb at 'creating' articles so my article isn't done yet. If I knew someway to CREATE an article but not have it publish until I am done then I would have something to work on, but since I have to create as a complete page I am still putting together a text file on my computer that I am cutting and pasting to see PREVIEWS of.

Comment: @randomblink See [Wikipedia:Starting an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Starting_an_article) for some help with that. Basically, you can either write the unfinished article in your userspace (e.g. `User:randomblink/InsertIMG`), or you can use [the Article Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Article_wizard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape brackets on wikipedia, you'll want to use the HTML code for the bracket symbols:

`[Insert&#91;IMG&#93;]`

Comment: Is this listed somewhere in the WikiHelp docs? I looked all over Google and Wikipedia to no avail?!

Comment: Well, I think they do have a section that says to use the HTML code in the link. For a `[`, it would be `&#91;`, for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup#Nowiki

Comment: That's how you format link here, using Madkdown, it won't work on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you need to replace the `]` character with `&#93;` (the HTML entity for that character). This means that an internal link to a page called `InsertIMG` with the description `Insert [IMG]` would be: `[[InsertIMG|Insert [IMG&#93;]]`. And an external link with the same description linking to http://www.insertimg.com would be: `[http://www.insertimg.com Insert [IMG&#93;]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Wikipedia's [Page name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Page_name#Technical_restrictions_and_limitations) page says

> A pagename cannot contain any of the following characters: # < > [ ] | { } _ (which all have special meanings in wiki syntax);

You can discover this by using the Insert Link button in Wikipedia's editor and typing *Insert[IMG]* as your target wiki page. This causes "Invalid title" to appear above the edit box.

However, you can put all kinds of things in external links, not that this is what you need :-)

[Wikipedia's Help:Link:Disallowed characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Link#Disallowed_characters) page says you need to use percent-code escape sequences for disallowed characters, so you can use this jumble

`[http://Insert%20%5BIMG%5D.com Insert&#91;IMG&#93;]`

to create a link which appears as

> Insert[IMG]

on a wiki page, previews as

> insert[img].com

on mouseover in Firefox, and links to

> http://insert%20%5bimg%5d.com/